# How to generate unique keys for different two dimensional matrices having different sizes?

Tags: time-complexity, data-structures, hash, hash-tables, hashing

[image: Table containing different matrices with their sizes along with output values]

**No. of rows in the table (as given in image) is not known beforehand . The problem I am dealing with generates different 2-D matrices based on the input data given. As soon as a matrix generates it should be placed in this kind of table (as a row) along with its output value. I have taken eight rows , but it can be anything. (eight rows = eight matrices )**

My main task is to find key value pair for each row in the table in image (given) for applying hashing. The first column is size of matrix ,second column is matrix elements and the third column is some output value ( getting output values by applying some algorithm , which is not the matter of concern here ). **For every row, the first two columns together should uniquely represent a key and the third column should be value . If I get the same key again , I won't compute the value again ; I will just reuse the value .**

For example fourth row is a 2*2 matrix . If I get exactly the same matrix again , then I won't compute its output value again. I will directly use that previously calculated output value .

**So I wanted to know how to form a key here ? What hash function can I use ? I am doing all these to avoid repeated calculations and to reduce time complexity.**

Comment: Convert your matrix to a string and apply any hash function.

Comment: Which hash function will work best in this case ? I can't afford even a single collision . @YuvalFilmus

Comment: A standard hash function. Unfortunately, there is no way to guarantee that there are no collisions.

Comment: How about djb2 ? Another question is - say matrix A = {(1,2),(3,4)} meaning two rows and two columns ; and matrix B= {(1,2,3,4)} , meaning one row and four columns . When we covert matrix into string , will A and B produce two different strings ? @YuvalFilmus

Comment: It's up to you how you convert the matrix into a string. Presumably in your case the strings will be different.